# Any reason to prefer to seed a DB table from 0 rather than from 1?

Tags: sql-server, identity-column

*Any reason to prefer to seed a DB table from 0 rather than from 1?*

I'm referring to the simple case when a new DB table is being created with a unique index column of type Int, and the developer can choose if the first entry in that identity column is a 0 or a 1.

Comment: Are you referring to Microsoft SQL Server's "identity" columns?

Comment: +1 Valid question, found something interesting thought to share: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04ff86f3-b4a9-4cb1-8bde-86927e7c06ef/identity-column-set-to-seed-at-1-inserts-first-row-with-id-0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in SQL Server you start `identity columns` with 1.

It is a common practice to use `DEFAULT` `NULL` to `0` when the right side of `LEFT JOIN` isn't matched.

It's look as if the developer is thinking of `identity column` row as the index in a vector, this is a mistake, you can `DELETE` rows it will have holes.

Comment: Right, the reason a colleague was looking to make his table start at 0 was so that it would mirror an enum in his C# code (they default to zero)

Comment: If the data in the database is meant to mirror the enum, that data is by definition *not* a SQL Server identity, and shouldn't be represented as one - it comes from a source outside of the database. Consider using a non-IDENTITY column matching the C# enum values as a key.

Answer (score 0):

The default is normally 1.

Using 0 could be considered ambiguous, and I can't see any reason why you'd want to prefer 0 over 1.